# Errors in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have the following procedure in oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure getPrecioMayorActual(PAR_ID_SUBASTA DECIMAL, 
outi out sys_refcursor) IS
 var1 decimal;
BEGIN
open outi for
        SELECT (p.MONTO_OFRECIDO) into var1 
        FROM (SUBASTA AS s) INNER JOIN (PUJA AS p) ON (s.ID_PUJA_MAYOR = 
p.ID_PUJA) 
        WHERE (s.ID_SUBASTA = PAR_ID_SUBASTA);
END getPrecioMayorActual;
```

The problem is that i'm getting the following errors:

```
Error(5,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(6,23): PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I've looked everywhere but I just can't manage to see what the problem is. I'm pretty sure that it must be something quite easy, but is my first time using this and I can't find anything useful on the web. Can anyone give me a hand please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Removing `as` keywords is enough like the following(for `table` aliasing they can not used, but can be used for `column` aliasing, optionally):

```
create or replace procedure getPrecioMayorActual(PAR_ID_SUBASTA DECIMAL,
outi out sys_refcursor) IS
 var1 decimal;
BEGIN
open outi for
        SELECT (p.MONTO_OFRECIDO) into var1
        FROM (SUBASTA s) INNER JOIN (PUJA p) ON (s.ID_PUJA_MAYOR =
p.ID_PUJA)
        WHERE (s.ID_SUBASTA = PAR_ID_SUBASTA);
END getPrecioMayorActual;
```

In addition, even if the above syntax is correct, there's no need using  paranthesis in the `SELECT` statement, and `PROCEDURE`'s name at the end. Then, you may prefer writing your PROCEDURE as the following :

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE getPrecioMayorActual(PAR_ID_SUBASTA DECIMAL, outi out sys_refcursor) IS
  var1 decimal;
BEGIN
 OPEN outi FOR
 SELECT p.MONTO_OFRECIDO
   INTO var1 
   FROM SUBASTA s INNER JOIN PUJA p ON s.ID_PUJA_MAYOR = p.ID_PUJA
  WHERE s.ID_SUBASTA = PAR_ID_SUBASTA;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need var1 since you are passing cursor to outi.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure 
getPrecioMayorActual(PAR_ID_SUBASTA DECIMAL, 
outi out sys_refcursor) AS
BEGIN
open outi for
        SELECT (p.MONTO_OFRECIDO) 
        FROM (SUBASTA AS s) INNER JOIN (PUJA AS p) ON 
(s.ID_PUJA_MAYOR = 
p.ID_PUJA) 
        WHERE (s.ID_SUBASTA = PAR_ID_SUBASTA);
END getPrecioMayorActual;
```